# How do I create a UICollectionView cell with a specific class?

Tags: ios, swift

I am migrating an Objective-C class to Swift. I use the collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath: to return a cell of a custom class.

How do I do what I want to do using Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language change makes no difference. Cocoa works the same way regardless of whether you talk to it with Swift or Objective-C. You register the cell class with collection view (probably in your `viewDidLoad`) — or the cell nib if the cell is to be loaded from a nib — and in your `cellForItem` you dequeue it, configure it, and return it.

Comment: Right, but what call do I use in Swift?

Comment: I don't know what "call" and "use" mean. Please read my answer: Cocoa is just Cocoa. Language changes nothing. It's all the same methods throughout. The docs tell you both the Objective-C and the Swift names for everything. Just change the language pop-up. For example, this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618029-collectionview?language=objc is the same as this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618029-collectionview and so on.